EM field of time dependent spherical current
A field of a time dependent rotating spherical current could be described by $\mathbf{J} = \sin \theta \; h(t) \delta(r-a) \hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}$.
First I related the current to the magnetisation. Since for a surface current $\mathbf{K}$, the magnetization satisfies the equation $\mathbf{K} =\mathbf{M} \times \hat{\mathbf{n}}$ we get
$$
\mathbf{M}|_{r =a} = k(t) \hat{\mathbf{z}}.
$$
The Hertz potential $\boldsymbol{\Pi}_m$ satisfies the equation
$$
 \nabla^2 \boldsymbol{\Pi}_m - \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \boldsymbol{\Pi}_m = -\mu_0 \mathbf{M}
$$
since the magnetiazion is non-zero only in the $\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ direction and utilizing the spherical symmetry of the problem I assumed that $\boldsymbol{\Pi}_m = \Pi_z(r,t) \hat{\mathbf{z}}$, then the equation for the potential is
$$
\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} \left(r \Pi_z(r,t) \right)   - \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2 }\Pi_z(r,t)  = -\mu_0 H(t) \delta (r-a).
$$
Now this is where I begin to get a little wonky. I try to solve the homogeneous equation.
I first make the substitution $\Pi_z(r,t) \rightarrow 1/r \tilde{\Pi}_z(r,t)$, then the equation reduces to.
$$
\partial_{rr} (\tilde{\Pi}_z(r,t)) = 1/c^2 \partial_{tt} ( \tilde{\Pi}_z(r,t)).
$$
This can be solved with the general solution by d'Alambert, we then get
$$
\tilde{\Pi}_z(r, t)=\frac{1}{2}[\tilde{f}(r-c t)+\tilde{f}(r+c t)]+\frac{1}{2 c} \int_{r-c t}^{r+c t} \tilde{g}(s) d s.
$$
We can substitute back, see this question. We get
$$
r \Pi_z(r, t)=\frac{1}{2}[(r-c t) f(r-c t)+(r+c t) f(r+c t)]+\frac{1}{2 c} \int_{r-c t}^{r+c t} s g(s) d s
$$
I have no idea how to continue from there, somehow I would like to expand the field into spherical Bessel functions so that the field in regular at origin and an outgoing wave at infinity. Then impose the Maxwell boundary equation.
So the question is essentially how to expand the function $\Pi_z$ into the spherical Bessel functions appropriately? What confuses me also is that I would expect the resulting field to be a combination of $f(r- c t) + g(r+ c t)$.
Edit: The problem has been solved in at lest two articles. One by expanding the vector potential $\mathbf{A}$ into spherical Bessel functions (see this article). Another solution in this article, employs again the vector potential and solving the appropriate equations by Legendre transform.

Why don't you just use the standard expansion into multipole fields? Then there's no need for Hertz potentials (or any potentials) and you immediately know which multipole you need in this case, and which Bessel functions are describing the field. See Jackson Chapt. 16:  https://archive.org/details/ClassicalElectrodynamics2nd/page/n765/mode/2up?view=theater

By multipole field you mean the whole expansion into vector spherical harmonics?

Actually I would just conclude that there is only one: the magnetic dipole. (Following Jackson's complete theory is too much work, you can just check that the solution for a magnetic dipole field works. You just need to pick the expression for this solution from Jackson. With the $\ell=1$ choice for the radial Bessel functions of course).

By the way, you are trying too solve the wave equations using Green functions. They are known for your case: see for ex https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function . Once you get a Green function. The solution of your equation is a convolution of the right part and the Green function. Also, since you have a right part as a delta function and $H(t)$ term, the convolution passes very well. A convolution of two delta functions give another delta function

Are you are searching for the solution for the equation? Why is it necessary to write the solution as Bessel functions? Would any solution be enough?

@JosBergervoet I agree that $\ell = 1$ is the only one that survives. This can be solved problem by employing the retarded vector potential $\mathbf{A}$, then expansion into spherical Bessel functions is exactly such, that only $\ell = 1$ survives. But it's not clear to me that why that would be the case for the Hertz vector also... Since a derivative of spherical Bessel function with $\ell$ is proprotional to $\ell, \ell - 1$.

@PierrePolovodov, I will look into the convolution, thank you. As I said in the comment above this comment. The spherical Bessel solution seems appropriate since 1) you get such solution when solving the vector potential, 2) the physically appropriate field is such that it's regular at origin and an outgoing wave at infinity.
